# Why do B* instances have a significantly slower start time than F* instances on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, profiling

I was recently reading [Understanding and Profiling App Engine Cold-Boot Time](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-and-profiling-app-engine-cold-boot-time-908431aa971d) which discusses various items relating to cold-boot time of Google App Engine instances (i.e. the time it takes to start up an instance). While discussing the cold-boot time of an F2 instance, the author writes:

> (Note, if you’re wondering why the B1,B2,B4 instances have significantly slower time, we will talk about that in a future post)

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find this "future post" that the author references, and have not been successful at finding this idea mentioned in any of the Google App Engine documentation online.

As quick background, the F1, F2, etc. instances are the names of different classes of frontend instances on Google App Engine, while the B1, B2, etc. are the names of difference classes of backend instances. ([more information can be found in Google's documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard))

So my questions are:

- Is this still true?
- And if so, what is the cause of this discrepancy in cold-boot time?

Comment: A tangent... I don't think F and B stand for frontend and backend.  Neither is more "front" or "back" than the other.

Comment: @gaefan See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing where this terminology is mentioned explicitly under the billing section: "Instead, you see instance hours from the "B" classes reported as "Backend Instances", and instance hours from the "F" classes reported as "Frontend Instances"."

Comment: good to know!  I still don't think it makes any sense though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes), the difference between the F* and B* instances is just the scaling type.

Being that the only difference, if you take a look at the documentation regarding the [startup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#startup) of the different types, you will see that the B* instances are awaiting an additional request `/_ah/start` and won't handle any other request before replying to that one. Moreover, based on the response it may need to run additional logic, which also takes time.

In a normal situation, all three types of instance are started upon receiving the first request, called [*Loading Requests*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#loading_requests). BUT automatic scaling may have [warmup](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#warmup_requests) requests that reduce even further the latency in a new instance. The warmup requests are those that try to predict when the application will need a new instance. This prediction is made out of different metrics and the application might still face a loading request.

Although we cannot be sure whether the writer of the blog had this feature enabled or not because it's optional.